# how to use tomtom api with python requests. it returns a text "user inactive"

Tags: python, kivy, tomtom

i am trying to use the requests library with python to fetch data from the traffic api with python.
this is the link for website with api that should include the traffic data:

https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/services/4/flowSegmentData/relative0/10/json?point=52.41072%2C4.84239&openLr=true&jsonp=jsonp&key=3EeqxQCR2DNsYzRCT0RPIxUhlzAM3hQc

but it returns an "Developer Inactive" on the website . how to solve that and use the api

also i want to ask if this will work with kivy.

Comment: That API key comes from https://medium.com/@bhaveshpatelaus/monitoring-real-time-traffic-incidents-using-tom-tom-apis-using-python-in-databricks-and-power-bi-ecbb714366ef and as it's written there (in "Step 2"), *The example API Key is already deleted and to call these APIs, you need to register your account with TOM TOM.*.

Comment: you should avoid showing your API key. It is almost like showing your password.

Comment: i know that but this is free api. if it is paid, i will not

Comment: As a developer you are responsible for this key and for requests made with it.

Answer (score 0):

API request that you provided has an API key that is not existing anymore. I tried it with your API key that you provided in the comment and it worked. But you must notice that you copied it wrongly - there is an additional character at the beginning.